# CSS class affects grid but doesn't seem to be applied

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
  <! DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="style.css"> 

    </head>

    <div class = "row">

        <iframe class = "col-9" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=! 1m14!1m12!1m3!1d24850.723133556872!2d-77.05667797556558!3d38.87045329841728!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v14271431671" width = 75% height="450"></iframe>

        <div class = "col-3 app">This is where the filters will go</div>

    </div>
    <html>
```

and the CSS which sets up the 12 column grid is below:

```
    * {border: 1px solid red !important;
    }

    * { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .grid {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1200px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .row { width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        display: flex;
    }
    .col-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-9 {
        width: 75%;
    }
    .col-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

my question is about the part class `.grid {margin: 0 auto;max-width: 1200px; width: 100%;}`. When I remove it the elements of my row become stacked rather than aligned side by side.  In other words the `<div>This is where the filter will go</div>` goes below the Google Maps frame, instead of beside it even though they are in the same `.row` class container and the display is set to flex.  The `.grid` class isn't applied to anything yet it seems to be affecting the display of the elements in the row class.  Why?

Comment: I don't even see where you are setting the `.grid` class in your HTML.  Could you provide a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/xirifipusi/2/edit) of the problem?

Comment: Yes that's the problem.  the .grid class isn't in the html markup but when I remove it from the style sheet it affects the the alignment of the two elements when the page render in the browser.  It makes them stacked rather than side by side.

Comment: You're also missing a whole <body> ... this might be copy|paste fail or you didn't paste all relevant code - please update your post.

Comment: I noticed a rogue } that was blocking the css formatting.  Fixed now.   Thanks.